# Tinymce allow tab space indent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, textarea

I want to add constant tab space indent when user press TAB.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    indentation : '60pt',
    plugins: 'textcolor print preview importcss searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount imagetools textpattern noneditable',
    paste_as_text:true,
    //menubar: false,
    toolbar: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | fontselect fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist checklist | forecolor backcolor',
    //nonbreaking_force_tab: true,
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.on('keydown', function(e) {


            //

            //


          });
    },

});
```

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE has a plugin named `Nonbreaking Space` that will (when configured appropriately) inserted 3 spaces when you press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/nonbreaking/#nonbreaking_force_tab

The documentation covers the complexities of making this change as they relate to other plugins like `table` and `lists` so I would urge you to read the documentation in its entirety.

***One word of WARNING about doing this ...***

Changing the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key in this fashion will make it very difficult for people who rely on the keyboard to exit the editor and move to another form field as the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key is how you would typically do so.  If you want your form to be accessible this change will make that very difficult to accomplish.

Comment: I used this one only, but it is not giving results like word pad

Comment: when I press tab after : to create a list like a thing tabs are not in sync.

Comment: i want output like this --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMbn9.jpg

Comment: HTML does not really have a tab in the sense of it moving to a specific location - this is simply inserting 3 hard spaces to simulate a tab.  What you are after is a much more complicated request.  Can you do something like that with CSS - sure - but its not as simple as just inserting spaces on the press of a tab key.

Comment: but i saw some examples which implemented on textarea.

Comment: TinyMCE is an HTML editor - a text area is not.  Your example uses characters like `\t` which is not valid in HTML.  There is no "tab" character in HTML - therein lies the fun part.